# set_weights() in Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I have pretrained weights as np.array of shape `(3, 3, 3, 64)`. I want to initialize this Tensorflow CNN with those weights using `set_weights()` like I show below.

However, when I try that, the following error pops up: `ValueError: You called set_weights(weights) on layer "conv2d_3" with a weight list of length 3, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. Provided weights: [[[[-0.15836713 -0.178757 0.16782044 ...`

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.layers[0].set_weights(weights)
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())


adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(nb_train_samples/batch_size),
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=np.ceil(nb_validation_samples / batch_size),
    class_weight=class_weight
    )
```

My question is: how do I pass those `(3, 3, 3, 64)` shaped weights to initialize that CNN? I have already checked the weight shapes required for each layer and the shapes I am trying to pass and the required shape match.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are setting only the initial layer's weights? If it is acceptable to reuse a previously saved config I believe you can do with 
trained_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_keras_model) 
# Load the config of the original model
conf = trained_model.get_config()
# New model
new_model= tf.keras.Sequential.from_config(conf)
# Get config weights and init new model with same weights
new_model = new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` arguments like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# init_kernel and init_bias are initialization weights that you have
init_kernel = np.random.normal(0, 1, (3, 3, 3, 64))
init_bias = np.zeros((64,))
kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.constant(init_kernel)
bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.constant(init_bias)

conv_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                                    activation='relu',
                                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                    kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                                    bias_initializer=bias_initializer)
```

Note the kernel's and bias' shapes that I've chosen. The values with which you initialise your layer must have the exact same shapes.

Comment: This makes sense!! Thanks! So... would this `conv_layer` replace my first layer `layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))` ? Also, I think I don't understand the reasoning behind `init_bias` and `init_kernel`... If `weight` is an `np.array` of shape `(3, 3, 3, 64)`, how should I slice it to get `init_bias` and `init_kernel`? Much appreciated!

Comment: Conv2D has 2 weights: kernel of shape (3, 3, 3, 64) and bias of shape (64,). To set weights from pretrained model you need both bias and kernel.